# Wrap getters and setters on SharedPreferences class

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I want to re-use code and wrap getters and setters due to they have the same functionality.

I guess there is to make a common function for each type.

I consider it is better to maintain the specific properties instead of making all generic due to the code is clearer to access to those properties. For example: `MyPrefs.instance.prefOne`

SharedPreferences class with 2 functions "identicals":

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class MyPrefs private constructor() {

    companion object {
        private const val PREF_ONE = "prefOne"
        private const val PREF_TWO = "prefTwo"

        val instance = MyPrefs()
    }

    private lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

    fun init(context: Context) {
        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext.packageName
                + "." + MyPrefs::class.java.simpleName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    fun clear() {
        prefs.edit().clear().apply()
    }

    var prefOne: String
        get() = prefs.getString(PREF_ONE, "")
        set(prefOne) = prefs.edit().putString(PREF_ONE, prefOne).apply()

    var prefTwo: String
        get() = prefs.getString(PREF_TWO, "")
        set(prefTwo) = prefs.edit().putString(PREF_TWO, prefTwo).apply()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this nicely with [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Here's a very simple example implementation for storing just `String` preferences:

```
class PreferencesDelegate(val context: Context, val key: String, val defaultValue: String = "") {
    private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue)
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        sharedPreferences.edit()
                .putString(key, value)
                .apply()
    }
}
```

You can use this in an `Activity` the following way:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var pref by PreferencesDelegate(this, "key")

    fun foo() {
        pref = "test"
        println(pref)
    }
}
```

---

Or with an additional extension function for nicer syntax:

```
fun Activity.preference(key: String, defaultValue: String = ""): PreferencesDelegate {
    return PreferencesDelegate(this, key, defaultValue)
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var pref by preference("key")
}
```

---

There are people who already have nicer implementations of the same thing with delegates. Check out [this](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/kotlin-sharedpreferences-using-delegated-property/) blog post, and [this](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/KPreferences) and [this](https://github.com/takuji31/Koreference) library for example. There are probably many, many others as well.

Comment: This is the idea I wanted to apply. Thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

I have found an elegant solution thanks to the zsmb13's answer.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class DelegatedPreferences<T>(val prefs: SharedPreferences, private val defaultValue: T) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return getPreference(property.name, defaultValue)
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        setPreference(property.name, value)
    }

    private fun getPreference(key: String, defaultValue: T): T {
        with(prefs) {
            val result: Any = when (defaultValue) {
                is Boolean -> getBoolean(key, defaultValue)
                is Int -> getInt(key, defaultValue)
                is Long -> getLong(key, defaultValue)
                is Float -> getFloat(key, defaultValue)
                is String -> getString(key, defaultValue)
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return result as T
        }
    }

    private fun setPreference(key: String, value: T) {
        with(prefs.edit()) {
            when (value) {
                is Boolean -> putBoolean(key, value)
                is Int -> putInt(key, value)
                is Long -> putLong(key, value)
                is Float -> putFloat(key, value)
                is String -> putString(key, value)
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }.apply()
        }
    }
}
```

The specific preference class is now very simple and clean:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class MyPrefs private constructor() {

    companion object {
        val instance = MyPrefs()
    }

    val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        val context = App.instance
        context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName + "." + MyPrefs::class.java.simpleName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    fun clear() {
        prefs.edit().clear().apply()
    }

    var anyProperty: String by DelegatedPreferences(prefs, "")
}
```

And the call, very simple:

```
MyPrefs.instance.anyProperty = "Hello!"
Log.d("***", MyPrefs.instance.anyProperty) // Hello!
```